# Calculate coordinates of triangle corners when area is known

Tags: vectors

The three corners of triangle have following coordinates:

$A = (1,0,0)$

$B = (0,1,0)$

$C = (0,0,z)$

What is the positive value of $z$ when area of triangle is $4$?

I have tried:

$AB = [-1,1,0]$

$AC = [-1,0,z]$

$\begin{bmatrix}i & j & k\\-1 & 1 & 0\\-1 & 0 & z\end{bmatrix} = k + jz + iz$

$(k + jz + iz) / 2 = 4$

$k + jz + iz = 8$

But I cannot solve $z$. Could I have some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area $\mathcal{A}$ of a triangle $ABC$ can be obtained with
$$\mathcal{A}=\frac{1}{2}\left|\overrightarrow{AB}\times\overrightarrow{AC}\right|.$$
Then you should write
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{z^2+z^2+1^2}=4.$$
**EDIT:**
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{z^2+z^2+1^2}=4 & \Longrightarrow\sqrt{2z^2+1}=8\Longrightarrow\\
& \Longrightarrow2z^2+1=8^2\Longrightarrow\\
& \Longrightarrow2z^2=63\Longrightarrow\\
& \Longrightarrow z=+\sqrt{\frac{63}{2}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: So the value of $z$ is $3.5$? $z + z + 1 = 8$?

Comment: You should take squares on both sides, then $z^2+z^2+1=8^2$.

Comment: Yes but then if I square root both sides again it's $z + z + 1 = 8$ Thus, $2z = 7$

Comment: Welcome by me in MSE (Sebastiano user also of TeX.SE).

Comment: @Sebastiano, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

You can't solve the equation since you incorrectly equating a vector with a scalar.

Instead, you should use the "length" of the vector on the left.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal projection of $C$ on the segment $AB$ is a point $P$ of the form $(t,1-t,0)$. The value of $t$ must be chosen so that $PC$ and $AB$ are orthogonal, that is, so that$$(-t,t-1,z).(-1,1,0)=0.$$Therefore, $t=\frac12$. So, the area of the triangle is$$\frac12\times\text{length of }AB\times\text{length}PC=\frac12\sqrt2\sqrt{\frac12+z^2}=\sqrt{\frac14+\frac{z^2}2}.$$So, take $z=3\sqrt{\frac72}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

This is an isosceles triangle, with basis $AB$, hence, if $I$ is the midpoint of $[AB]$, its area is equal to $\frac12 AB\cdot CI$. Note that $I$ has coordinates  $\bigl(\frac12,\frac12,0\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   A &= (1,0,0) \\
   B &= (0,1,0) \\
   C &= (0,0,z) \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   a &= BC &=\sqrt{1+z^2} \\
   b &= AC &=\sqrt{1+z^2} \\
   c &= AB &=\sqrt 2 \\
\end{align}

$$s = \frac 12(a+b+c) = \sqrt{1+z^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

\begin{align}
   s-a &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\
   s-b &= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \\
   s-c &= \sqrt{1+z^2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}
\end{align}

$$s(s-c) = (1+z^2) - \frac 12 = z^2 + \frac 12$$
$$(s-a)(s-b) = \frac 12$$

\begin{align}
   |ABC| &= \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} &\text{(Heron's formula)}\\
       4 &= \sqrt{\frac 12 \left(z^2 + \frac 12 \right)} \\
      32 &= z^2 + \frac 12 \\
      63 &= 2z^2 \\
     z^2 &= \dfrac{63}{2} \\
       z &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{63}{2}}
\end{align}